Coil Jetpack compose not showing image
The problem I am facing is in if block.
if (imageState is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) 

this line is throwing an error incompatible types: AsyncImagePainter.State.Error and AsyncImagePainter I don't know what to do. I am new to kotlin and android developement
this is my code
@Composable
fun Product(product: Product) {
    val imageState = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(product.thumbnail)
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL).build()
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
            .height(300.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
    ) {

        if (imageState is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        }

        if (imageState is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp),
                painter = imageState.painter,
                contentDescription = product.title,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = "${product.title} -- Price: ${product.price}$",
            fontSize = 17.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = product.description,
            fontSize = 13.sp,
        )
    }
}

I tried watching different youtube tutorials as well as coil documentation but it is hard for me to follow those documentation

Although you named the variable imageState, its type is AsyncImagePainter and not AsyncImagePainter.State.
Just retrieve the state property and compare that, then you a re ready to go:
if (imageState.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
    // ...
}

Also, is there a reason why you don't use SubcomposeAsyncImage() instead of Image?

Two ways to fix it:

Without delegate
val imageState = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest
              .Builder(LocalContext.current)
              .data(product.thumbnail)
              .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
              .build()
    )



And use state.value
if (imageState.value is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {


Using delegate

    val imageState by rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            model = ImageRequest
                  .Builder(LocalContext.current)
                  .data(product.thumbnail)
                  .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                  .build()
    )

And use without .value
if (imageState is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {

